# How to get getPhoneCount() in below Android R

Tags: android

How to get the device is supported for Dual Sim for Below Android R.

I am using the following code. But I am getting a deprecated warning for telephony.getPhoneCount().

How to get for below Android R. Or do we need to add @SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )?

```java
public boolean isDuelSim(Context pContext) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephony != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            return telephony.getActiveModemCount() == 2; //Dual SIM functionality
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return telephony.getPhoneCount() == 2;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getPhoneCount()` method seems to be the right way of checking if the device supports dual SIM on api levels from M to Q. If you are compiling your project for R or greater, you will get the deprecation lint warning.

IMO, your implementation is correct and if you need to suppress that warning then either add the `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation to your `isDualSim()` method signature or the `//noinspect` comment above the `telephony.getPhoneCount()` call.

BTW, I'd also suggest considering the case when `getActiveModemCount()` or `getPhoneCount()` returns a 3. Whether a tri SIM phone should pass your dualSIM test or not depends on your use case, of course.